# Why can't I map this simple object to text in XML in Java/Jersey?

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, moxy

I have a REST API created with Jersey in Java.
For one request I'd like to return in JSON a list of tuples of pair of coordinates.
For this, I have a class that's a wrapper for an `ArrayList`, a `Tuple2` class and a `Coords` class.
I use the `javax.xml.bind.annotations` for automatically generating the XML/JSON of my classes.

But for a reason that I don't understand my `Coords` class can't be me mapped to XML.

I have tried different types of attributes (`Integers` instead of `int`), having the `@XmlAttribute` at different places (before the attributes and before the getters) and different `XmlAccessType` (`PROPERTY` instead of `NONE`) but the results were the same.

Here is my Coords class :

```java
package model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import static javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType.NONE;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(NONE)
public class Coords {
    @XmlAttribute private int x;
    @XmlAttribute private int y;

    public Coords(final int x, final int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Coords() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }
}
```

And here is how it is present in my Tuple2

```java
package model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import static javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType.NONE;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(NONE)
public class Tuple2 {
    private Coords c1;
    private Coords c2;
// ...
    @XmlAttribute 
    public Coords getFirst() {
        return this.c1;
    }

    @XmlAttribute 
    public Coords getSecond() {
        return this.c2;
    }
// ...
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
[EL Warning]: moxy: 2019-10-27 15:01:08.586--javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
Exception Description: The @XmlAttribute property first in type model.Tuple2 must reference a type that maps to text in XML. model.Coords cannot be mapped to a text value.
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-50096] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: The @XmlAttribute property first in type model.Tuple2 must reference a type that maps to text in XML.  model.Coords cannot be mapped to a text value.]
oct. 27, 2019 3:01:08 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
GRAVE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class model.ActionList, genericType=class model.ActionList.
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is coming from the misuse of the xml annotations. You are defining a `Tuple2` to be an xml root element by annotating it with `@XmlRootElement`, and its fields to be xml attributes by annotating the get methods with `@XmlAttribute`. Which translates to:

```xml
<tuple2 first="first_attributes_vale" second="second_attributes_value" />
```

Now, both fields are of type `Coords`, which is declared to be another xml element by annotating the `Coords` class with `@XmlRootElement`, and its fields to be xml attributes. When `Coords` gets serialised to xml, it will be:

```xml
<coords x="value" y="value" />
```

The problem occurs when serialising `Tuple2`. Its fields are supposed to be xml attributes, but `Coords` is another xml element. Xml attributes cannot contain nested elements, but only values.

## Solution

Depending on what you want, you can solve this in two different ways. Although, I wouldn't recommend the second approach, because it's odd (even though it works) and will incur extra effort on the client side (see explanations below).

#### First Approach

Annotate the `getFirst()` and `getSecond()` methods with the `@XmlElement` annotation.

```
package model;

import static javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType.NONE;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(NONE)
public class Tuple2 {
    private Coords c1;
    private Coords c2;

    public Tuple2(Coords c1, Coords c2) {
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;
    }

    public Tuple2() {
        c1 = new Coords(0, 0);
        c2 = new Coords(0, 0);
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Coords getFirst() {
        return this.c1;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Coords getSecond() {
        return this.c2;
    }
}
```

This will produce a result that looks like this:

```
<tuple2>
    <first x="2" y="4"/>
    <second x="12" y="12"/>
</tuple2>
```

#### Second Approach

This is the odd way of solving it. It works, but it incurs extra effort on the client side, because the values of `Coords` are encoded as string values and will require parsing on the receiving side.

Change the return type of `getFirst()` and `getSecond()` methods to be `String` and override the `toString()` method of `Coords`.

```
package model;

import static javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType.NONE;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(NONE)
public class Tuple2 {
    private Coords c1;
    private Coords c2;

    public Tuple2(Coords c1, Coords c2) {
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;
    }

    public Tuple2() {
        c1 = new Coords(0, 0);
        c2 = new Coords(0, 0);
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getFirst() {
        return this.c1.toString();
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getSecond() {
        return this.c2.toString();
    }
}
```

Override the `toString()` method of `Coords`:

```
package model;

import static javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType.NONE;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(NONE)
public class Coords {
    @XmlAttribute private int x;
    @XmlAttribute private int y;

    public Coords(final int x, final int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Coords() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Coords [x=");
        builder.append(x);
        builder.append(", y=");
        builder.append(y);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

This will produce a result similar to this:

```
<tuple2 first="Coords [x=2, y=4]" second="Coords [x=12, y=12]"/>
```

The values of the attributes `first` and `second` will be whatever the `toString()` method of `Coords` returns.

Comment: @hforrat what you are referring to as the third approach is in my first approach. :) (just saying). Anyway, I am glad I helped you.

Comment: Oh yes of course, I was so excited to put this bug behind me that I immediately tried something just after finishing reading your explanation.
Anyway, thanks again, I am extremely grateful.